# I am using the SMTPLib to send an email to gmail account

Tags: python, python-3.x, smtp, smtplib

I have two messages.One is the HTML Message and the other one is a simple plain text message.I am attaching both of them to the MIMEMultipart variable(tmessage) but when the email get send, i can only see the second attached message in my inbox. I cannot figure out why...Here is my code

```
import smtplib
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
host='smtp.gmail.com'
port=587
message="<h1>Hey i have received a 3rd  email message using Python</h1>"
userName='teaching807@gmail.com'
password='teaching807299'
connection = smtplib.SMTP(host,port)

connection.ehlo()
connection.starttls()
_from=userName
_to=userName
connection.login(userName,password)

tmessage = MIMEMultipart("alternative")
tmessage['Subject']="Html Message"
tmessage['From']=_from
tmessage['To']=_to
plain_message = "This is a plain message"
html_message="""<html><body><h1>Students Marks</h1><p>These are the students 
Marks</p></body></html>"""
msg1=MIMEText(html_message,'html')
msg2=MIMEText(plain_message,'plain')
tmessage.attach(msg1)
tmessage.attach(msg2)

connection.sendmail(_from,_to,tmessage.as_string())
connection.quit()
```

In the inbox only msg2 can be seen

Answer (score 0):

try removing "alternative" from tmessage, it works for me in Outlook.

```
tmessage = MIMEMultipart()
```

Answer (score 0):

By adding two parts, you're offering alternatives. From the [python docs](https://docs.python.org/3.1/library/email-examples.html):

> According to RFC 2046, the last part of a multipart message, in this case the HTML message, is best and preferred.

You're adding the plain text last, making that the prefered one. You'll never see both the plain and html.

Answer (score 0):

According to the bottom part of [this](https://docs.python.org/2/library/email-examples.html) documentation, the type "alternative" is simply that, to provide an alternative plain text when HTML is not supported for whatever reason.

You're only viewing one message because your email account/browser supports html. 
You will only ever see one email, because only one is sent. What you view depends upon what type of data your email/browser can support.